# Flask WTForm validation failing for SelectField...why?

Tags: python, validation, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm using Flask and WTForm to make a web app, so far my other two fields validate fine, but the SelectField is throwing the error 'Please choose a pet.' as specified by myself i.e it thinks thinks that it isn't receiving a valid input. The SelectField.choices match up to the options rendered into HTML so what am I doing wrong?

**app.py**

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
from wtforms import IntegerField, StringField, SelectField, validators, 
ValidationError
from flask import Flask, request, flash, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)


pChoices = [('-1', '-----'),
            ('0', 'Cat'),
            ('1', 'Dog'),
            ('2', 'Parrot'),
            ('3', 'Hamster')]


class paymentForm(Form):
    productF = SelectField('productF', [validators.input_required("Please choose a pet.")], choices=[pChoices], coerce=int)
    buyer_id = StringField('buyer', [validators.input_required("Please enter your name.")])
    paid = DecimalField('paid', [validators.input_required("please enter payment amount")])


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    form = paymentForm(request.form, csrf_enabled=True)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash('Order Placed Successfully', 'success')
        data = form.data
        record_order(data)
        print(data['price'])
        return render_template('confirmation.jinja',
                               pets=PETS,
                               title='Confirmation Page',
                               form=form, error=form.errors,
                               ** context)
    elif not form.validate_on_submit:
        flash('Submission error, please check the form', 'success')
    return render_template('index.jinja',
                               title='Order Form',
                               form=form,
                               error=form.errors,
                               **context)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

**index.jinja**

```
{% extends 'base.jinja' %}

{% block main %}
  <form method="post">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="product" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Pet:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select id="productF" class="form-control" name="pet" onchange="Update()">
          <option value="-1">-----</option>
          {% for pet in pets %}
            <option value="{{ loop.index -1 }}">{{ pet.name }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="buyer" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Buyer:</label>
      {% for message in form.buyer_id.errors %}
         <div>{{ message }}</div>
      {% endfor %}
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="buyer_id" name="buyer_id" placeholder="Buyer" value="{{ buyer_id }}" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="paid" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Amount Paid:</label>
      {% for message in form.paid.errors %}
         <div>{{ message }}</div>
      {% endfor %}
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="paid" name="paid" placeholder="Amount Paid" value="{{ paid }}" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% if form.errors %}
    {{ form.errors }}
    {% endif %}
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Place Order</button>
      </div>
    </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() 
}}"/>
  </form>


{% endblock %}
```

**edit** I have updated the code with productF as the field name in the jinja file and I still receive the error. The `Pets` object is loaded into the HTML page as a JSON object instead of app.py but as far as I can tell the values are identical; this is how the select element appears from the inspector:

```
<select id="product" class="form-control" name="product">
          <option value="-1">-----</option>         
            <option value="0">Cat</option>          
            <option value="1">Dog</option>          
            <option value="2">Parrot</option>          
            <option value="3">Hamster</option>          
        </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining `pChoices` as a list

```
pChoices = [('-1', '-----'),
            ('0', 'Cat'),
            ('1', 'Dog'),
            ('2', 'Parrot'),
            ('3', 'Hamster')]
```

But then wrapping it in another list in the `SelectField` definition:

```
productF = SelectField(..., choices=[pChoices], ...)
```

Using `choices=pChoices` should fix it.

**Edit:** you also have `pet` as the field name in the form jinja template, you probably want to use `productF`.

**Edit 2:** there's a mismatch on the way you're defining the values for `pChoices` and the field coercion. Either remove `coerce=int` from the form field or set the first value of the tuples in `pChoices` to be integers, not strings.

Comment: Still throws the same error after changing it to `choices=pChoices`

Comment: Ok So I took out `coerce=int` but still getting the error.

Comment: according to your edit the name of the field is still wrong `<select id="product" class="form-control" name="product">` it needs to match that of the field in the form